# What type of framework to use

Tags: selenium, test-automation-framework

For automation of banking projects, please suggest what type of selenium framework(Hybrid, keyword driven or DDT) is ideal for opening a bank account scenario?

Comment: What is hybrid framework?

Comment: Can you please give more about what is your requirements in framework ?

Answer (score 3):

It's often hard to tell what framework you need for your tests until you  start writing tests. Once you have your tests you may find what are the limitations of your implementation. Perhaps you don't need any specialized framework at all.

Therefore, I suggest you to work on this iteratively:

1. Write a number of tests for opening a bank account.
2. Is there any pattern among the tests? For instance, if you see that most of your tests are having same parameters (e.g., street and country fields) they may be a good candidate for parametrized tests: one test method launched for a set of different values.
3. Refactor your tests into parameterized tests. You may not need any new framework for that. For instance, most XUnit testing libraries support parametrized tests out of the box. For instance, in Java TestNG or JUnit5.
4. Come back to point 2 if you see more patterns and refactor your tests iteratively.